# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed in C# licensing method

Tags: c#, cryptography, licensing, rsa

in my project I'm Doing a licensing method where after the user enters the license key his product will be activated. Im using the following code but I'm getting an exception thrown
saying "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed". The following is my code

```
public void ValidateProductKey()
        {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider _cryptoService = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        string productKey = "G7MA4Z5VR5R3LG001AS1N5HA3YHX05";
            byte[] keyBytes = Base32Converter.FromBase32String(productKey); //Base32Converter is my customized method which returns byte of values;

            byte[] signBytes = new byte[2];
            byte[] hiddenBytes = new byte[16];
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(keyBytes))
            {
                stream.Read(hiddenBytes, 0, 8);
                stream.Read(signBytes, 0, 2);
                stream.Read(hiddenBytes, 8, hiddenBytes.Length - 8);
                keyBytes = stream.ToArray();
            }

            byte[] sign = _cryptoService.SignData(signBytes, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
            byte[] rkey = new byte[32];
            byte[] rjiv = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(sign, rkey, 32);
            Array.Copy(sign, 32, rjiv, 0, 16);

            SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();

            try
            {
                hiddenData = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(rkey, rjiv).TransformFinalBlock(hiddenBytes,0,hiddenBytes.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

When reaching the "hiddenData" variable I get an exception thrown as "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed". Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You look to be generating the key and IV for the Rijndael decryption by signing your `signBytes` array using SHA1/RSA, however from the code you've given, you don't initialize the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` used in the signing process with a key pair, as such it will have a randomly generated key, and so the result of the signing process will be different every time. Consequently the key/IV being used in the Rijndael decryption are not going to be the same as that used to encrypt the `hiddenData` when you created the license key.

There are a number of other issues with the method you're using in itself, but that falls outside the scope of your question.

Comment: I have few other things that need to be taken care of after i get the value in "hiddenData" however i thought that as the code doesnt go beyond this point so i just posted it.

Comment: Can you tell what are the issues with the method? So that i can correct them. Also if you can guide me with any other method to validate a license key.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that no licensing mechanism is perfect, then we have to ask, what provides the security of your method? The problem here is that there basically is *no* security. Sure you're using RSA, Rijndael/AES, - pretty decent algorithms in their respective classes, but you're using them in a way that basically voids their security because the end-user(/attacker) has *everything* they need to create their own license keys if they know the method (which with .NET is easily recovered using Reflector/dotPeek etc., even if you decide to obfuscate it).

Comment: Previously i decided to get the hardware signature of a pc. But that seemed to be a totally new field and provided the less time i went with this option. But since im new to all these cryptography things im still stuck on this process and cant move further.